# Error data=0x when trying to send arguments to a function in smart contract

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethers.js

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="verify(string,bytes)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
```

I have a smart contract with this func

[image]

When I'm trying to call it I have an error, and my data is 0x

console.log(form.message)

> 0xea7edde6151005625eb65b5a399b535ced4e16cc6c6314fa889c32bab5d5af24

console.log(sig)

> 0xa73897b83a472ddd42ceea082b19c7db93deff86f347427537079d6889e0f9056a69bde252c4e47051d442e43b4c5eb724b30003c657ca8bc2b85e658ffa55701b

```
const verifiedContract = await contract.verify(form.message, sig);
```

Comment: Probably, the contract generated an error, and it is returning an empty answer. It doesn't seem related to the input parameters. Can you share verify function source code?

Comment: I answered this issue, i was using wrong net for the provider